# How to close UIAlertView using MonkeyTalk on iOS8?

Tags: ios, ios8, uialertview, monkeytalk

Until iOS7 we were happy using *MonkeyTalk (2.0.8)* for our automated UI tests. `UIAlertViews` could be easily closed / confirmed via `app.button("OK").tap` (JavaScript) or `Button OK Tap` (MonkeyTalk Script).

This is not working on a device running iOS8. *MonkeyTalk* complains about not finding a button named "OK". Instead, you can tap the corresponding label. Finding a label named "OK" and tapping it works fine. At least optically. In iOS7 we've got a notification, that the current window resigned active, when the alert view has been closed. In iOS8 this notification is not sent any more, when the alert view is closed via `app.label("OK").tap`, but IT IS sent, when the alert view is manually closed by tapping on the device.

*Spark Inspector* revealed that there is a `_UIAlertControllerShimPresenterWindow` on top of everything (`[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow`) and it remains there, if the alert view is closed via *MonkeyTalk*. It even catches all user input and renders the app useless until restarted.

So, what is the correct / preferred way to close a `UIAlertView` in iOS8 with *MonkeyTalk*?

Answer (score 0):

Try View("Ok").tap.Label on AlertVieew has given us problem in ios8 as well.

Which version of MT are you using .

Thanks

Comment: We are currently using version 2.0.6. They recently released version 2.0.9 which says, that iOS8 support has been added. I couldn't evaluate this new version until now, but I will leave a reply, if the UIAlertView handling has been improved in this version.